# Capture data from dynamic field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I have an form that require some information. The patient name field have the functionality to be added dynamically if there are more patients. But, I can't capture data of the added field, I imagine I should capture it within an object, but it didn't work the way I tried.

###### State and Functions

```
const [patients, setPatients] = useState([{ fullName: '', cns: '' }])

const newPatientField = () => {
  const newPatient = (
    <div
      key={patients.length}
      className='flex-row mb-4 rounded-md'>
      <div className='flex gap-4'>
        <Input
          type='text'
          className='border'
          placeholder='Nome completo'
        />
        <Input
          type='number'
          className='border'
          placeholder='CNS'
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )

    setPatients([...patients, newPatient])
  }
```

###### Rendering patientField

```
{patients.map((patient, index) => (
  <div
    key={index}
    className='flex gap-4 mb-4'>
    <Input
      type='text'
      className='border'
      placeholder='Nome completo'
      value={patient.fullName}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const newPatients = [...patients]
        newPatients[index].fullName = e.target.value
        setPatients(newPatients)
      }}
    />
    <Input
      type='number'
      className='border'
      placeholder='CNS'
      value={patient.cns}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const newPatients = [...patients]
        newPatients[index].cns = e.target.value
        setPatients(newPatients)
      }}
    />
  </div>
))}
```

###### Add/Rmv buttons

```
 <div className='flex flex-row gap-4'>
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => {
      handleNewPatient()
      newPatientField()
    }}
    className={`bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded shadow-md ${
      patients.length > 1 ? 'w-2/3' : 'w-full'
    }`}>
    Adicionar novo paciente
  </button>
  {patients.length > 1 && (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={handleRemoveLastPatient}
      className='bg-red-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded shadow-md w-1/3'>
      Remover último paciente
    </button>
  )}
</div>
```

I expect to capture the data from the added fields. Now I'm having these errors on console:

"Cannot add property fullName, object is not extensible"

"Add property fullName, object is not extensible"

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in OnChange method even though you are creating a copy of the state but that copy is shallow, you can learn more about that by searching shallow vs deep copy

```
setPatients((prevPatients) => {
    // Create a new array and a new object for the modified patient
    const newPatients = [...prevPatients];
    newPatients[index] = {
      ...newPatients[index],
      fullName: e.target.value,
    };
    return newPatients;
  });
```

why are you saving the whole jsx function into the state. According to the code provided you have to append an object with pateint initialValues at the end.

```
const initialPatientData = {name:'', cns:'' }


function handleNewPatient() {
setPatients(prev => [...prev, initialPatientData]
}
```

`{patients.map((patient, index) => render stuff` will keep rendering patient items, no need to add whole jsx to it.

Comment: I made the changes to the code and it worked. Thanks for the explain!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).